# Doctrine2 - Polymorphic Associations to Same Entity from Two Different Entities

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, polymorphic-associations

I am still trying to understand polymorphic associations in Doctrine2.

As I understand it, basic polymorphic associations work by using inheritance.  If, for example, I had tables/classes `OWNER`, `CAT` and `DOG`, then the way to enable `$owner->pet` to point at either the `CAT` or the `DOG` table, would be to have them each extend a fourth class, `PET`, which is known as a mapped superclass. Then `$owner->pet` could return either a `CAT` or a `DOG` depending on what had been assigned, and Doctrine2 would be able to distinguish them.

That's simple enough. But what if I want to have two polymorphic associations which can point at the same object? For example, lets say that I have a table of `ADMIRALS`, each of which could command a `FLEET` or a `PLANET`.  Let's also say that I have a table of `SECTORS`, each of which could contain a `PLANET` or a `MOON`.

Let's assume that I want `$admiral->command` to reference both `PLANETS` and `FLEETS`, and that I want `$sector->contents` to reference both `PLANETS` and `MOONS`.  `PLANET` can't extend both `command` and `contents` as mapped superclasses.  Is there a different way to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

you can try ResolveTargetEntityListener [see](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/docs/en/cookbook/resolve-target-entity-listener.rst)

you can point admiral's **command** property to an Interface, which is implemented by both PLANETS 
and FLEETS

the same is with sector's **contents**

Comment: From the doc at your link: "In most circumstances, only a single object should implement this interface as the ResolveTargetEntityListener can only change the target to a single object."

Seems like this would foreclose use for this purpose, since both PLANETS and FLEETS could not both implement the same interface. Am I missing something?

Comment: i use it already for my own use case,  where property **tarif** could be pointed to 2 other entities, and entity **Tarif** points with property **subject** to both of them. in my case it worked out